# Почему выводятся не все элементы коллекции AutoCompleteCustomSource?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, winforms

Так выглядит обычное автозавершение для фамилии. Я отправляю в коллекцию автозавершения результаты запроса:

`SELECT FAMILY FROM Persons WHERE (FAMILY IS NOT NULL)`

циклом запуская ридер:

`while (reader.Read() == true)
                textBox_FAMILY.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add((string)reader[0]);`

(я знаю, что лучше обращаться к датасету, а не к БД, пока рассмотрим такой пример) всё работает, отображаются все фамилии из базы:

[image]

Я хочу, для предотвращения дублирования клиентов, при вводе фамилии выводит вместе с ней имена и отчества, чтобы начавший создавать нового клиента менеджер увидел, что такое ФИО уже есть и остановился, вот так:

[image]

Для этого я использую такой запрос:

`SELECT FAMILY, FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME FROM Persons WHERE (FAMILY IS NOT NULL)`

и такой ридер:

`while (reader.Read() == true)
                textBox_FAMILY.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add((string)reader[0] + " " + (string)reader[1] + " " + (string)reader[2]);`

Вот только автозавершение во втором случае работает некорректно - показывает не все варианты, которые есть в БД.

MaxLength текстбокса = 150, всё должно уместиться... Я не понимаю, где я делаю не правильно, подскажите пожалуйста, почему всё так и как это исправить?